# Why is the last 'if' statement in Pinescript not executing?

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I don't understand why the last 'if' statement is not getting executed (Pinescript V5). Can someone pls help?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay = true)

if false

    if false
        label.new(bar_index, high, color = color.orange)
        
        if true
            label.new(bar_index, high, color = color.red, yloc = yloc.abovebar)

    else if true
        label.new(bar_index, low, color = color.red, yloc = yloc.belowbar)

        if true
            label.new(bar_index, high, color = color.white)

else 
    if true
        label.new(bar_index, high, color = color.orange)

        if true
            label.new(bar_index, high, color = color.white, yloc = yloc.abovebar)
```

Comment: I don't understand why @sideshowbarker delete my answer. I asked pinescript support why the last if true will work only if we add a new line after the lebel.new line

Comment: Looks like a bug. Reported to the pine team.

Comment: @StarrLucky - you are right, it was a bug. Even I have reported and got response from them that it was corrected. This happened in Jun 22, but missed to update here. Thank you for your help.